# Cannot see members of a structure declared as nullable

Tags: vb.net, nullable, structure

In VB.NET, why can't I see a member of a structure when I make it a nullable type?

Example:

```
Public Structure myNullable  
    Dim myNullVar As Integer  
End Structure

Sub Main()  
    Dim myInstance As myNullable 'This works.  
    Dim myNullableInstance? As myNullable 'This works.   
    myInstance.myNullVar = 1  'This works.     
    myNullableInstance.myNullVar = 1   'This doesn't work.  
End Sub
```

Comment: what are you doing that needs a structure? I don't see much of a use for structures for most .net programs, especially people learning .net

Comment: what are you doing that would not work with Dim myNullVar As 'Integer?' wrapped in a class? or as the value you are passing around if this is all that structure contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you need to use the `Value` property to *fetch* the value. However, `System.Nullable<T>` is immutable - the `Value` property is read-only. It will be returning a copy of the value, so even if you *could* change the field, it wouldn't do what you want.

This is actually a good thing - value types *should* be immutable. Mutable structs are horrible - if the fact that `Nullable<T>` makes it hard to use your type pushes you down the immutability route, that's great.

Make your field read-only, and add a constructor to let you pass in the value. Then instead of trying to modify the nullable value, assign an entirely new value to the variable.

Comment: Ah bizarre struct issues, another reason I don't like structs.

Comment: While I rarely write structs myself, the problem is really with *mutable* structs here.

Comment: I've had mutable structs bite me before, and since I had no idea what was going on... I switched the word structure to class. and all the sudden all my code worked. So I abandoned trying structs.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have noted, you can access the inner value of a nullable with .Value. But they suggest you to do myNullableInstance.Value.myNullVar = 1 which doesn't work.

That's because of the way structures work. When you change a member of a struct, a new struct instance is created. You can't do that in this case because it would modify the Value property of the Nullable class, which can't be done directly, because Value is ReadOnly.

This would work though:

```
Dim myInstance as myNullable
myInstance.myNullVar = 1
myNullableInstance = myInstance
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Nullable<T>` structure exposes the underlying value via the `Value` property. Therefore, you need:

```
myNullableInstance.Value.myNullVar = 1
```

Comment: I get this error when I try that: "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment."

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that this does **not** work:

```
myNullableInstance.Value.myNullVar = 1
```

Basically, you would be assigning to some copy of the structure that was returned by the Value property.

It's not really a problem, because usually structures are made to be *immutable* as a best practise. You could work around this with some assignments back and forth, but as others have posted, you should reconsider using a class instead. That way, you don't need any Nullable either, because you can just use a null reference.

Answer (score 0):

Nullable structres are a pain and there is no good reason that Microsoft has to make things so difficult. Its done this way to make it easier for the compiler writers not the language users.

In fact there is not good reason why we need to make reference types and values types behave differently. Microsoft is trying to hide the logical pointers(addresses) but it doesn't work very well because it makes things more difficult not easier. Every rule and restriction imposed on a language makes things more difficult and results in ineffeciency, runtime errors and higher development costs.

We would all be better off if we went back to logical typed pointers. Then we wouldn't need fancy words like immutable. (immutable means unchangeable!)

My suggestion is to ditch the Nullable structures and make it a class which is always nullable.